# Django. A Unicode BUG/Error on auth model on a remote DB

Tags: python, django, unicode, python-social-auth

first of all, I'm not sure what the title of the question should be, I accept suggestions.

I noticed this error when I got a Unicode Error on django admin coming from a model. Since it was on production (Heroku), I tried to replicate it locally, I entered the same data locally and I found the problem: Somehow I ended up with a user with a username `José`...

If you try to create a user in the admin and write `José` in the username, it will give you an error and it will not let you create the user (at least this happens to me locally) ... **how could I have ended up with a user with a username `José` on production**?

The `Unicode` error came from a `__unicode__` method on another model that used the user username as representation.

I'm using Python Social Auth and the user logged in using Facebook.

**EDIT**

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "Notificacion: %s - %s - %s" % (self.perfil_actor, self.tipo, self.libro.titulo)
```

`self.perfil_actor` is a FK to my "Perfil" model, which has a unicode method that looks like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "Perfil: %s" % (self.usuario.username)
```

When I say that "I can't create a username called José" I'm refering to the admin, this:

[image]

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have a user named José ; plenty of Django users (and core contributors) are from non-English speaking countries. If there is a bug, it is in that `__unicode__` method; you should probably show it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added some extra info.

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace of the actual error that causes this. With an admin panel that appears to be in spanish its quite likely you'll get lots of spanish named users too if thats your locale... is this python2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: I guess you are using python 2.7.x, so mark your strings as unicode by prepending `u` before them, e.g. `return u"Perfil: %s" % (self.usuario.username)`

Comment: @Todor - you should make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

> return "Notificacion: %s - %s - %s" % (self.perfil_actor, self.tipo, self.libro.titulo)

So I'm guessing as best I can without a stacktrace, but:

The `%` operator on a byte format string tries to convert its non-basestring parameters to byte strings using `__str__`.

Django's base `Model` provides a `__str__` implementation that calls `__unicode__` and encodes the result to UTF-8. So the value for `self.perfil_actor` used by the `%` operator ends up being the byte string `'Jos\xc3\xa9'`. (This is a questionable bit of design on the part of Django.)

At least one of `self.tipo` and `self.libro.titulo` are probably Unicode strings. The `%` has a special case for `unicode` in that if any of the arguments are `unicode` strings, it promotes the whole string to Unicode.

But! When this happens it *doesn't* switch to calling `__unicode__` on its non-basestring parameters as it would have done had you used a Unicode format string in the first place. (This is a questionable bit of design on the part of Python.)

So now you have a byte string `'Jos\xc3\xa9'` being concatenated into a Unicode string. To do so, the bytes have to be decoded again back to Unicode. Which doesn't work because the implicit ‘default encoding’ that Python uses for that purpose is ASCII, and 0xC3 and 0xA9 are invalid bytes in ASCII. Boom UnicodDecodeError!

To summarise, automatic byte-string/unicode-string conversions in Python 2 are a horrible pain. (Python 3 helps by getting rid of them so it fails sooner.)

Avoid the automatic conversion by keeping your strings either all-bytes or all-Unicode. Since `self.tipo` and `self.libro.titulo` seem to be Unicode, and you want the `__unicode__` rendering of `self.perfil_actor`, the format string you use to put them all together should also be Unicode:

```
return u"Notificacion: %s - %s - %s" % (self.perfil_actor, self.tipo, self.libro.titulo)
```

> how could I have ended up with a user with a username José on production?

The default Django user model has a `username` field with a RegexValidator that doesn't allow non-ASCII characters. This is a questionable but [deliberate](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20694) design decision.

This is why the admin interface prevents entering `José`. However, this is only a form-level restriction, not a database constraint. The username can get into the database through other means... in particular, if you have a custom signup form that alters UserCreationForm (or doesn't use it at all), then it might bypass the default validation and ignore the RegexValidator.

If you need to allow entering non-ASCII usernames in the admin too, you could [use a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) with a more forgiving validator, or [use a custom admin form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).